# PHP - Wrong Username / Password - How to Echo it Properly

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to code a login form in PHP. The login/logout is working fine, however I'm a bit curious as to the proper way to echo "Wrong Username / Password" for my particular code.

Here's my code (from login.php which is included on index.php in a sidebar):

```
<form method="post" action="security.php">
<input name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username"><br />
<input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password"><br />
<input name="login" type="submit" value="Log in" class="login">
<small><input type="checkbox"> Keep me logged in</small>
</form>
<?php
if ($failed == 1) {
echo "Wrong Username / Password";
}
?>
```

And here's my code for security.php:

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';

// username and password sent from form 
$tbl_name = 'users';
$username=$_POST['username']; 
$password=$_POST['password'];

// To protect MySQL injection
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $username and $password, table row must be 1 row
if($count == 1)
{
// Register $username, $password and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_start();
$_SESSION["username"] = $username;
header("location:home.php");
}
else {
$failed = 1;
header("location:index.php");
}
?>
```

As you may or may not see, I've tried to use a variable set in security.php called $failed which is set in security.php and used in an if in login.php to echo the failure message. I know that isn't even close to working, but it was the only way I could see to tell you what I'm trying to do. Any help?

Comment: Why not just check if `$_SESSION['username']` has been set (with `isset()`)? If it hasn't you know the security check failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this **security.php**:

```
if($count == 1)
{
// Register $username, $password and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_start();
$_SESSION["username"] = $username;
header("location:home.php");
}
else {
header("location:index.php?msg=failed");
}
```

And this in **index.php:**

```
if (isset($_GET["msg"]) && $_GET["msg"] == 'failed') {
echo "Wrong Username / Password";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add LIMIT 1 to your sql query.

Otherwise do a `header("location:index.php?success=false");`

Then you can check for it:

```
if( !empty( $_GET[ 'success' ] ) && ( $_GET[ 'success' ] == FALSE ) )
{
echo 'failed login';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your security code, in the login failed section you could change:

```
$failed = 1;
header("location:index.php");
```

to:

```
$failed = 1;
include "./login.php";
```

That way, when authentication fails, the user will be returned to the login screen without a 301 redirect in-between. This will work well if all php files are in the same folder.